# Launch event on finger slide over the View in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, slide, uitapgesturerecognizer

Is anything of such possible to achieve in Xamarin for Android and iOS?

I was using tap events on the views so far, but I am not sure how to induce event when I actually tap anywhere, and then slide finger over the taprecogniser or other gesture recogniser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a [Swipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe) gesture

```
var leftSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Left };
leftSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;

myView.GestureRecognizers.Add(leftSwipeGesture);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks Jason. I didn&#39;t realize it&#39;s that easy. Brief explanation on MS site made me think swipes 
are for something totally different. Thanks again

Comment: However when I try to create new SwipeGestureRecognizer I get error that type or namespace of such does not exist

Comment: are you using an older version of Forms?

Comment: Possibly. I will look into it now

Comment: Yes, that was 3.1. I updated to the latest package and I can see the namespace now. Thank you again

Comment: I implemented the solution as you suggested but it does not meet my needs exactly as I expected. Can you please have a look at my other question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525394/track-position-of-fingers-on-screen-while-sliding-finger-in-xamarin-forms-app